# Command output to file, new lines at beginning

Tags: bash, scripting, solaris, lubuntu

I'm rewriting some 20+ year old Unix scripts and I want the output to go to the screen and a file. I know this is possible with `tee`. Is there a similar command that stacks new lines on top, at the beginning of a file? I'd like the file to be output in reverse chronological order.

The script output will redirect to a WWW folder. For remotely viewing the output, I want to F5 in a browser and have new lines at the top of the browser window.
I'll recycle the file (`cp log log_$(date '+%Y%m%d') && cp /dev/null log`) everyday to keep it from growing too large.

I was hoping `tee` had a complimentary utility like `cat` has with `tac`, but alas no luck.

Comment: please don't post your question in multiple sites.

Comment: Cross site post http://askubuntu.com/q/593019/216503

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to atomically modify a file to insert variable amounts of data at the beginning. This would involve copying the previous contents of the file to the necessary offset and then writing the new data over the beginning. This process would become more and more difficult as the amount of data to copy increases.

I'd solve this by using a script (e.g. `php`) that uses `tac` on the file and sends the resulting output to the browser.